# Power Query to load Web data but no table shows

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm actually reading "Power BI from Rookie to Rock Star". The book mentioned Power Query can load data from web (http://www.boxofficemojo.com/alltime/world/?pagenum=1&p=.htm), and shows "table 0"

[image: Book's version]

However, when I followed his step, I cannot find any tables but only "Document" in my Navigator

[image: My version]

May I know why is this happen and how can I get the table data ?
Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me...
Do you have the latest version of Power B I Desktop?

**Hope I'm not being presumptious, but can you access the webpage directly from your location?**

Get Data > From Web

[image]

[image]

The site itself:
http://www.boxofficemojo.com/alltime/world/?pagenum=1&p=.htm

[image]

Comment: I can access this web page from my location. It might because my power BI is not latest version. Thanks anyway~